# Trazer registro de cada ID com a data de alteração mais recente

Tags: php, sql, oracle10g

Estou trabalhando com banco Oracle e PHP, preciso retornar apenas um produto de cada com a data de alteração mais recente, as tabelas são as seguintes.

produto

[image: produto]

preco

[image: preco]

Já tentei vários tipos de consulta, mas sempre obtenho resultados duplicados.

E tentando agrupar com a seguinte consulta

```
SELECT a.CODPROD, a.DESCRICAO, b.PVENDA, b.CODPROD FROM PCPRODUT a, PCPRECO b
GROUP BY b.CODPROD
```

Obtenho o seguinte erro:

> "ORA-00979: não é uma expressão GROUP BY"

Comment: Tentou agrupar a consulta? como você tentou a consulta?

Comment: Quando tento agrupar obtenho o seguinte erro: "ORA-00979: não é uma expressão GROUP BY"

Comment: A consulta é "SELECT
  CODPROD,
  DESCRICAO,  
  PVENDA
  
FROM
  PCPRODUT, PCPRECO WHERE PCPRODUT.CODPROD = PCPRECO.CODPROD"

Comment: [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/173009/edit) a pergunta e coloque a consulta que vc tentou com o group by

Comment: Todas as colunas que estão no `select` deve estar no `group by`

Comment: Realizei a seguinte consulta agora, porém a pagina fica só carregando e não me retorna nada.
"a.CODPROD, a.DESCRICAO, b.PVENDA, b.CODPROD, max(b.DATAALTER) FROM PCPRODUT a, PCPRECO b GROUP BY a.CODPROD, a.DESCRICAO, b.PVENDA, b.CODPROD"

Comment: QUando vc testa no banco obtem o resultado desejado?

Comment: Não, acontece a mesma coisa

Answer (score 0):

Cara faz um tempo que não uso o Oracle, tenta algo desse tipo:

```
SELECT a.CODPROD, a.DESCRICAO, b.PVENDA, b.CODPROD, MAX(b.DATAALTER)
FROM PCPRODUT a, 
INNER JOIN PCPRECO b ON a.CODPROD = b.CODPROD
GROUP BY a.CODPROD, a.DESCRICAO, b.PVENDA, b.CODPROD
```

Comment: Agora puxou, porém ainda com alguns resultados duplicados.

Ex:

40 REFRESCO PO QUALIMAX ABACAXI 1 KG 4.51 40 2013-04-05 20:40:55
40 REFRESCO PO QUALIMAX ABACAXI 1 KG 5.34 40 2015-03-20 07:08:03
40 REFRESCO PO QUALIMAX ABACAXI 1 KG (null) 40 2015-06-08 00:00:00
74 REFRESCO PO QUALIMAX LARANJA 1 KG 7.74 74 2016-08-05 19:15:59

Comment: veja se ajuda http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/512214-selecionando-item-max/#entry2030107

Comment: Ajudou, obrigado!